# log4net giving Oracle database connection error

Tags: oracle, log4net, adonetappender

I'm having this issue where on my desktop log4net configured to log to the Oracle database logs without any problems, but when I deploy the same thing on the web server it is ginving me the below error

```
log4net:ERROR [AdoNetAppender] ErrorCode: GenericFailure. Could not open database connection [data source=XXXXXXXX;User ID=XXXXXXX;Password=XXXXXX]. Connection string context [ConnectionString].
```

the desktop system in 32-bit while the server is a 64 bit. Entity Framwework works without any problems on both systems wiuth Oracle. I have installed both ODAC121010Xcopy_x64 and ODAC121010Xcopy_x32 on the server.

Comment: You should edit your database password.

Comment: the password i have given is correct. as i said it work on my desktop

Comment: Thats not what I mean you've putted your database password on a public website. You should edit it to xxxxx or whatever.